# Google Dart Regions?

Tags: dart, region

In c# there's something called regions, which can be useful to structure your code. I was wondering if there is something similar for Google Dart?

Comment: You can add your vote here https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/285

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dart does not support regions as part of the language specification.  However, many IDE tools offer this feature using formatted comments.  See the answer below identifying Android Studio and IntelliJ as two such examples.

Comment: [Visual Studio Code Custom Folding Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maptz.regionfolder)

Answer (score 29):

```
//#region Test 

//#endregion
```

That works in Android Studio & IntelliJ.

Comment: Good point.  IDE tools typically offer this feature, not language specifications.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: This works in Visual Studio Code as well.

Comment: @NamithaReval It doesn't work with my VS Code. Do I need to install any extension?

Comment: @TuanvanDuong, yes, sorry. I use this extension - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maptz.regionfolder