# equivalent to C# #region in Dart?

Tags: c#, flutter, dart

Recently I started to program in flutter, and I come from the C # language. For some projects that I am developing for my work, I would like to make the code more readable, and I remembered that in C #, we have #region and #endregion. Is there any equivalent property in Dart, or that does the same thing?

```
#region MyClass 
public class MyClass
{  
    static void Main()
    {  
    }  
}  
#endregion
```

Comment: Checkout that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322412/google-dart-regions

Comment: Please note that regions in C# are considered a code-smell by many: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53086/are-regions-an-antipattern-or-code-smell